# how to store upload files in public folder in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

my hosting provider has disabled the `symlink()` function for security reasons, the Laravel default path to uploading files is in the storage folder, so I need to change the upload path from storage directory to public directory in my Cpanel `public_html` folder structure like this:

```
- files:
  -- Laravel framework files and folders such as:
     --- app
     .
     .
     .
     --- storage:
         ---- app:
              ----- public:
                    ------ uploads
- assets:
   -- CSS files and Javascript files and static images
- .htaccess 
- favicon.ico
- index.php
- robot.txt
- web.config
```

I want to be like this (I mean when a file upload it's will be stored in the store in `public_html` => `uploads` folder):

```
- files:
  -- Laravel framework files and folders such as:
     --- app
     .
     .
     .
     --- storage:
         ---- app:
              ----- public
- assets:
   -- CSS files and Javascript files and static images
- uploads:
  --- user uploaded files
- .htaccess 
- favicon.ico
- index.php
- robot.txt
- web.config
```

I add this code in `config\filesystem.php` in `disks` array:

```
'uploads' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root'   => public_path(), // previously storage_path();
        ],
```

and in my VideoController the upload method code is:

```
public function uploadVideo (Request $request) {
        $target = $request['target'];

        //Get filename with the extension
        $fileNameWithExt = $request->file($target)->getClientOriginalName();

        //$fileNameWithExt = $request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalImage();
        //Get just file name
        $filename = pathinfo($fileNameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        //Get just ext
        $extension = $request->file($target)->getClientOriginalExtension();
        //Filename to store
        $fileNameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
        //Upload Image
        $path = $request->file($target)->storeAs('public/uploads/' . $target, $fileNameToStore);
        
        // I add this code to create uploads folder in pucli_html
        Storage::disk('uploads')->put('filename', $filename);

        return 'storage/uploads/'. $target .'/'.$fileNameToStore;
    }
```

but it creates a public folder inside the files folder

Comment: `$request->file($target)->move(public_path('uploads'), $fileNameToStore);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to change any `filesystems.php`. You upload your `video` or `image` anywhere in your project like below

```
$upload_path = base_path('../');

$path = $request->file($target)->move(

     $upload_path.'/uploads/', $fileNameToStore

);
```

Comment: It is good but I need to go one level up the code you write it's retuned `home/studioaleph/public_html/video/files/` I need `home/studioaleph/public_html/video/`

Comment: @AmirHossein, I update my answer. Hope It will help you

Answer (score 0):

create a new storage disk in config/filesystems.php:

```
'uploads' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root'   => public_path(),
],
```

replace the FILESYSTEM_DRIVER value in .env with new disk name(uploads)

and you can upload the file in easy way

```
$file = $request->file->hashName();
$request->file->store('uploads');
```

Comment: did you see my folder structure ?

Comment: Why do you want to upload the file to the root?

Comment: because I put my public folder files is there like CSS and javascript files used in the project

Comment: I try your code and I get `Call to a member function store() on null error`

Comment: just because you are unable to access index.php from public

Comment: replace file with your key which is coming from request. i think it's target

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236772/discussion-between-moolchand-sharma-and-amir-hossein).